# Maven Generated Sources inside Different Project

Tags: java, maven, build, generated-code

I have a Java web project that is built using Maven. The project has some annotated classes to generate some sources at build time using a template (velocity). Everything works well so far, I'm using the generated sources flawless.

Right now I need to use those generated classes in a different project. I'm wondering how can I tell maven to package those sources in an additional jar. I would like to use that generated jar in both my main project and the new one as a new dependency.

Any Ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution is to create a separate project which contains only the generated parts which will by default create a jar file as usual which gives you simple the possibility to reuse that in different other projects. With the following structure this is simple to solve.

```
  +-- root (pom.xml)
        +--- generated (pom.xml)
        +--- main (pom.xml)
        +--- other (pom.xml)
```

In you main project just simply define a dependency to your generated project like

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>what.ever.group</groupId>
  <artifactId>generated</artifactId>
  <version>${project.verison}</version>
</dependency>
```

and the same in your `other` module.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand the order of the projects in modules. The matter is that I don't know how to extract my generated sources out of my main project. They are in my generated-sources directory but how can I tell maven to package it in the "generated" project you suggest?(I wouldn't like to copy paste those files) Thanks again!

Comment: May be you should take a look at the [templating-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/templating-maven-plugin/). The thing sounds to me like a job for a plugin what you are doing.